# eigen/core error while building heasillidar_sdk

Tags: linux, build, eigen

I was trying to build https://github.com/HesaiTechnology/HesaiLidar_General_SDK and it showed that Eigen/Core was missig.I am new to this so I dont know what went wrong where.It would be a great help if someone could help.The error has been given below

````
[  8%] Building CXX object src/PandarGeneralRaw/CMakeFiles/PandarGeneral.dir/src/pandarGeneral_internal.cc.o
In file included from /usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/io/pcd_io.h:42,
                 from /home/rock/Downloads/HesaiLidar_General_SDK/src/PandarGeneralRaw/include/pandarGeneral/pandarGeneral_internal.h:20,
                 from /home/rock/Downloads/HesaiLidar_General_SDK/src/PandarGeneralRaw/src/pandarGeneral_internal.cc:20:
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/pcl_macros.h:75:10: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
   75 | #include <Eigen/Core>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [src/PandarGeneralRaw/CMakeFiles/PandarGeneral.dir/build.make:76: src/PandarGeneralRaw/CMakeFiles/PandarGeneral.dir/src/pandarGeneral_internal.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:153: src/PandarGeneralRaw/CMakeFiles/PandarGeneral.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2```

EDIT:Fixed it!
running ln -s /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen /usr/include/Eigen
worked
````

Comment: Many programs assume /usr/include/Eigen/. .......... Most OS have `/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/` . ............. A quick workaround : `cd /usr/local/include/ && sudo ln -s /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/` . .......... Then no errors with "HesaiLidar_General_SDK", Ubuntu 20.04 .